# Phoenix/EmberJS Websocket access with actions

Tags: javascript, ember.js, phoenix-framework

I have a basic Ember frontend app which connects to a Phoenix backend via a websocket in an initializer. Next I want to be able to use `chan.push("new_msg", {body: "test"})` to send a message to the Phoenix channel.

Obviously, I can't do this from the initializer itself, but that is the only place where 'chan' is defined and I don't know how to access it from another location.

I want this to happen on a action from an `{{input action="sendMessage()"}}` so I have tried several things such as putting the `sendMessage()` function in the initializer and calling it in a component action etc... But any time I try to access the initializer from another file (or vice versa) I get an error saying the function is not defined. I know initializers should not be used this way of course, I just don't know where else to put the code such that I can access the websocket connection I have defined.

The majority of the code related to this problem matches what you will see in this guide: http://chrismcg.com/2015/07/04/teaching-ember-cli-to-talk-to-phoenix-sockets/ . Unfortunately this doesn't cover how to make use of this websocket connection from the frontend for beginners.

Comment: Your action syntax is wrong, it should be `{{input action="sendMessage"}}`

Comment: Yeah, I keep slipping into this one. Bad habit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a job for services, see the respective documentation at http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/.
The service would have a `chan` property to hold the channel, and the `sendMessage` action, then you'd just inject the service in the right context and do something akin to:

```
{{input action=(action service.sendMessage)}}
```

That's using [closure actions](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/) to trigger the service's action directly.

Comment: Awesome! That solved everything perfectly! Mind if I ask a quick syntax question though? I need to pass and argument (the contents of the input as a message) to the sendMessage function, but haven't been able to figure it out exactly. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do `(action service.sendMessage attributeName)` and `sendMessage` will be called with `attributeName` as the first argument. If you set `value=attributeName` I believe it should also send it?

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks again!